# Type of DocuSign license required for customers to access Integration

Tags: docusignapi

I am in the process of creating a DocuSign integration. Would anyone happen to know which type of account customers need to purchase from DocuSign in order to leverage my DocuSign integration? Can't the credentials for any account outside of a free trial be used to access a DocuSign integration as a customer? What's odd is that most integrations I've seen in the past require the user to have at least a Professional Account, which I believe is now called Standard (@ $25 per user).

Any feedback is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, the account you use to develop the integration has nothing to do with the account used by customers to access your integration. 
As long as the account has "API Access" it could use any integration. These includes most of the plans that are sold including the lowest tier (web and mobile) and even some trial accounts get access to the API (at least while the trial is on). I can't get you a through answer about every single type of account as we have so many, but in general you should find most accounts would be able to use your integration.